# MS Access - Multiple Search Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqpqp.jpg)

I need your assistance with creating a form for multiple search field in MS Access. My form has 10 fields in which users can input data to get search result in a Split Form. The intended user have the option to enter search parameters in one or more fields to get results (e.g: vendor, state, license number, date parameter for license expiration date, date added, etc). I am currently having trouble with the VB and hit a brick wall.

If none of the search fields are used I want all results to display.

If there are search criteria in any of the search fields, I want the results to display any of the criteria in the search fields (e.g.: search for Vendor 'Amazon' and search by State 'FL'. I want results to come back all records in table for Amazon and records with FL as the state not Amazon and FL records but any records in the table that have Amazon or FL).

Below is the VB coding that I have:

```
Sub Search()

Dim tempCriteriaForReport As TempVar

Dim strSearch, strCriteria, strLicenseType, SearchDateRange As String

Dim strVendor, strState, strDrugManufacturer, strDeviceManufacturer, strFederalDrugIdentifier, strCommentsFKA, strLicenseNumber, strExpirationDate, strDateAdded As String

Dim task As String

Dim varItem As Variant


'''=========== code for VENDOR
If Not IsNull(Me.txtVENDOR) Then
    strVendor = "([Vendor] like ""*" & Me.txtVENDOR & "*"")"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & strVendor & ")"
End If

'''=========== code for STATE
If Not IsNull(Me.txtSTATE) Then
    strState = "([State] like ""*" & Me.txtSTATE & "*"")"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & strState & ")"
End If

'''=========== code for DRUG MANFACTURER
If Not IsNull(Me.txtDRUGMANUFACTURER) Then
    strDrugManufacturer = "([Is Vendor a Drug Manufacturer] like ""*" & Me.txtDRUGMANUFACTURER & "*"")"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & strDrugManufacturer & ")"
End If

'''=========== code for DEVICE MANFACTURER
If Not IsNull(Me.txtDEVICEMANUFACTURER) Then
    strDeviceManufacturer = "([Is Vendor a Device Manufacturer] like ""*" & Me.txtDEVICEMANUFACTURER & "*"")"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & strDeviceManufacturer & ")"
End If

'''=========== code for FEDERAL DRUG IDENTIFIER
If Not IsNull(Me.txtFEDERALDRUGIDENTIFIER) Then
    strFederalDrugIdentifier = "([Federal Drug Facility Establishment Identifier] like ""*" & Me.txtFEDERALDRUGIDENTIFIER & "*"")"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & strFederalDrugIdentifier & ")"
End If

'''=========== code for LICENSE NUMBER
If Not IsNull(Me.txtLICENSENUMBER) Then
    strLicenseNumber = "([License Number] like ""*" & Me.txtLICENSENUMBER & "*"")"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & strLicenseNumber & ")"
End If

'''=========== code for LICENSE TYPE
If Not IsNull(Me.txtLICENSETYPE) Then
    strLicenseNumber = "([License Type] like ""*" & Me.txtLICENSETYPE & "*"")"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & strLicenseType & ")"
End If

'''=========== code for LICENSE EXPIRATION DATE range
If Not IsNull(Me.txtEXPIRATIONDATEFROM) And Not IsNull(Me.txtEXPIRATIONDATETO) Then
    SearchDateRange = "([Expiration Date] >= #" & Me.txtEXPIRATIONDATEFROM & "# and [Expiration Date] <= #" & Me.txtEXPIRATIONDATETO & "#)"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & SearchDateRange & ")"
End If

'''=========== code for DATE ADDED range
If Not IsNull(Me.txtDATEADDEDFROM) And Not IsNull(Me.txtDATEADDEDTO) Then
    SearchDateRange = "([Date Added] >= #" & Me.txtDATEADDEDFROM & "# and [Date Added] <= #" & Me.txtDATEADDEDTO & "#)"
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " And (" & SearchDateRange & ")"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. *I am currently having trouble with the VB and hit a brick wall.* is not a description.

Comment: The VB coding above isn't producing any results.

Comment: Eh... You're not doing anything with the string you're constructing. You probably should.

Comment: What is the expected / anticipated outcome of the code in question?

Comment: If there are a criteria in any of the search fields, I want the results to display any of the criteria in the search fields (e.g.: search for Vendor 'Amazon' and search by State 'FL'. I want results to come back all records in table for Amazon and all records with FL as the state not Amazon and FL records but any records in the table that have Amazon or FL).
If there is nothing in the search fields, I want all results to display.  Thanks for any assistance you guys can provide.  I truly appreciate it!!

Comment: A couple of concerns, you seem to be talking about a "search" and referencing some sort of table. However, the code listed would have no effect on either of those things. For instance: you **could** open a query with the code that would use the `strCriteria` in some sort of WHERE statement for a query. However, you would need to setup the query using a QueryDef wtihin the code and then open it dynamically. However, that sort of coding is open to SQL Injection, it really all depends on your needs. This may help with your research: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx

Comment: Here is a good example: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html -- there is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would strongly recommend reducing your criteria generation code to two `Subs` / `Functions` -- one for string criteria taking a single textbox, and one for datetime criteria taking a pair of controls.

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Comment: Andre- This helps tremendously.  If I have any questions, can I reach out to you?  Many thanks!